# There is no copy left to right in eclipse SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm using eclipse with SVN. But when I go to Team > Update to Revision, in the screen where appear the differences between left and right, only appear the options to copy the differences from remote to local repository, I'd like to copy from local repository to remote, but there is no options like that. I have to enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in that dialog you are comparing your local version with an already comitted revision. You cannot change the latter. If you want to commit your local changes on the left hand side, the solution is simple. Just don't overwrite it with the changes from the remote. Eclipse will then show a difference between your local revision and the repository which you can commit.